# Android Parse JSON

Tags: android, json, web-services

Using **getEvents** (below) i am able to show List of Events.

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Winter Festival",
            "multiOperatives": "1,3"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Summer Festival",
            "multiOperatives": "2,4"
        }
    ]
}
```

JSON to parse Operatives **getOperatives**

```
{
    "operatives": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "firstName": "Operative 1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "firstName": "Operative 2"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "firstName": "Operative 3"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "firstName": "Operative 4"
        }
    ]
}
```

but now i don't know ***how to show particular Operatives*** only, like i want whenever **user do tap on Summer Festival**, then i just need to show only ***two Operatives*** namely, *Operative 2 and Operative 4*....

**GetEventsActivity.java**:

```
public class GetEventsActivity extends ListActivity {

    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://myurl.tld/webservice.php?ws=getEvents&u=p&p=y";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_EVENTS = "events";

    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_MULTI_OPERATIVES = "multiOperatives";

    // Alert dialog manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    // Connection detector
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    // events JSONArray
    JSONArray events = null;
    String multiOperatives;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events);

         cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

            // Check for internet connection
            if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                // Internet Connection is not present
                alert.showAlertDialog(GetEventsActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                        "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
                // stop executing code by return
                return;
            }

        // Hashmap for ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of events
            events = json.getJSONArray(TAG_EVENTS);

            // looping through All events
            for(int i = 0; i < events.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = events.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                multiOperatives = c.getString(TAG_MULTI_OPERATIVES);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_MULTI_OPERATIVES, multiOperatives);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                contactList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                R.layout.activity_list,
                new String[] { TAG_NAME }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(GetEventsActivity.this, GetOperativesActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("multiOperatives", multiOperatives);
                startActivity(intent);                        
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**GetOperativesActivity.java:-**

```
 public class GetOperativesActivity extends ListActivity {

    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://myurl.tld/webservice.php?ws=getOperatives&u=p&p=y";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_OPERATIVES = "operatives";

    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "firstName";

    // Alert dialog manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    // Connection detector
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    // events JSONArray
    JSONArray events = null;

    String multiOperatives;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_operatives);

         if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
                new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();      
                    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
             }

         cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

            // Check for internet connection
            if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                // Internet Connection is not present
                alert.showAlertDialog(GetOperativesActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                        "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
                // stop executing code by return
                return;
            }

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            multiOperatives = intent.getStringExtra("multiOperatives");

        // Hashmap for ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of events
            events = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OPERATIVES);

            // looping through All events
            for(int i = 0; i < events.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = events.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                contactList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                R.layout.activity_list,
                new String[] { TAG_NAME }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

By using above code i am **able to fetch list of Events and Operatives**, but don't know how to show only required Operatives for an Event.....not all the Operatives...
like i want whenever **user do tap on Summer Festival**, then i just need to show only ***two Operatives*** namely, *Operative 2 and Operative 4*....

Comment: You just need to map `multiOperatives` with your `operatives' id`.

Comment: Hey @SilentKiller hi buddy but getting confuse, can you show me the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First modified code in GetEventsActivity.java: as given below

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            multiOperatives= contactList.get(position).get(TAG_MULTI_OPERATIVES);
            Intent intent = new Intent(GetEventsActivity.this, GetOperativesActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("multiOperatives", multiOperatives);
            startActivity(intent);                        
        }
    });
```

And than just modified the code of your GetOperativesActivity.java:- given as below

```
  try {

      String[] amultioperative=multiOperatives.split(",");
      List<String> arrmultiopera= Arrays.asList(amultioperative);

        // Getting Array of events
        events = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OPERATIVES);

        // looping through All events
        for(int i = 0; i < events.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = events.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

          if(arrmultiopera.contains(id)){
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            contactList.add(map);
         }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: now getting only 3 Operatives, whereas in some Events i have 2, in some 5, in some 3 and so on...and the magical thing is getting same 3 Operatives everytime, i guess a small issue here, check again

Answer (score 4):

As per my understanding , i am posting my answer let me know if you have query,

- `getEvents.json` will return all events in your first activity. Here `"multiOperatives": "1,3"` is contains number of `Operatives ID` in each event.That is doesn't matter if you have two `Operatives ID` or more then that like `"multiOperatives": "1,3,5,9"` , we just need that ID only.
- When you click on event you will change your activity with events details.
- At this stage you are calling `getOperatives` and that will return all `Operatives` which is not good thing at all.
- Pass Operatives with Intent as below ,

  `Intent intent = new Intent(GetEventsActivity.this, GetOperativesActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("multiOperatives", multiOperatives);
      startActivity(intent);`

  and in GetOperativesActivity.java, using this:

  `Intent intent = getIntent();
  multiOperatives = intent.getStringExtra("multiOperatives");`
- Now you just have to pass that `Operatives ID` when you call  `getOperatives` so that will return only return ID'S `Operatives`.
- `http://YOUR_URL/getOperatives.json?Operatives_ID="+multiOperatives`
- Just you need to change in your WEB-API query and that will change your web developer.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            TextView text = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.youroperativeid);
            String op = text.getText().toString();
            String[] idsval = op.split(",");

        for(int i = 0; i < idsval.length(); i++){

            try {

                    opers = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OPERS);

                    for(int i = 0; i < opers.length(); i++){
                      JSONObject c = opers.getJSONObject(i);

                     String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                     String fname = c.getString(TAG_FNAME);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        if(idsval.get(i).equals(id)){
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                     map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                }

                     opList.add(map);
                    }
             } catch (JSONException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
             }
        }
        }
    });
```

Comment: not clear, actually confuse how and where it will call getOperatives.json

Answer (score 0):

1. Parsing **getOperatives.json** you must create an `ArrayList` of
   your *Model/Bean*  **operatives**
2. When you get the click event on your `listview` then you must get
   the value for specific **TAG_MULTI_OPERATIVES** as you have added in
   the map by this statement  `map.put(TAG_MULTI_OPERATIVES,
   multiOperatives);`
3. Now you have the comma separated values and those can be easily
   split based on `,` and use the values stored in string array you may
   get the specific data from `Arraylist` by specific `getter()`

Comment: not clear, actually confuse how and where it will call getOperatives.json, can you show me the way by placing code

Comment: I only mean to read the file getOperatives.json like any other json file and then create an Arraylist of objects from it.